# Custom show/hide links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I plan to apply a custom show/hide effect on link, such that when a user hovers on a link, a different link appears in its place. I'm not so good in javascript and here is what I was trying:

```
<div id="nav">
    <a href="#"><li id="a1">hover link 1</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li id="a2">show link 1</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li id="b1">hover link 2</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li id="b2">show link 2</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li id="c1">hover link 3</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li id="c2">show link 3</li></a>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
$("#nav a.li").hover(function () {
    (this.id.charAt(0)+"1").hide();
});
```

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8chbP/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `$` and need to add `#` befor `id` your also need to change selector as you do not have anchor with class li

*Change*

```
(this.id.charAt(0)+"1").hide();
```

*to*

```
$('#' +this.id.charAt(0)+"1").hide();
```

*Your code would be*

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8chbP/4/)**

```
$("#nav a li").hover(function () {
    $('#'+ this.id.charAt(0)+"1").hide();
});
```

**Edit** If you want to remove the item being hovered then use `$(this)`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8chbP/5/)**

```
$("#nav a li").hover(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Check my updated answer, is it what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't know why, but it's not happening on my system. Console is not showing any error.

Comment: That's the problem. The Console is clean. No error. Even if I try doing `$('body').hide()`..nothing happens!!